# How to put values back from php data to ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not even sure if my title is right. Anyway, I'm creating a page where users can submit messages / post and currently trying to figure out how to update the number of likes per post for a particular number of seconds using short-polling (i.e. setinterval) -- this is intentional for now. This is only a practice and I know I'm not using parameterized queries and short polling isn't ideal, but I'll park that for now. This may be my longest post, sorry but I was told this is way much more convenient than providing half baked inputs / questions.

I have this **Jquery**:

```js
function refreshPostLikes() {
  var postid_array = []; //establish array for postid
  $(".post .postid").each(function () {
    //get id for each post
    var postid = $(this).attr("value");
    postid_array.push(postid); //place all the postid in an array
  });
  updatePostLikes(postid_array); //pass the array
}

function updatePostLikes(postid) {
  setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/main/refresh-like.php",
      type: "post",
      data: { postid: postid }, //send postid array to php file
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data); //testing because I don't know how
      },
    });
  }, 20000); //just 20 seconds interval
}

refreshPostLikes(); //run function
```

Here's my **PHP file, refresh-like.php**!

```php
<?php
require_once '../connection.php';

$postID = trim(json_encode($_POST['postid']), '[]'); //convert array to string and remove square brackets to be a valid value for MySQL query

$likeQuery  = "select count(*) as total_likes from likes where post_id in ('.$postID.') group by post_id order by post_id desc"; //query number of likes
$likeResult = mysqli_query($conn, $likeQuery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($likeResult)) { //loop through the query
    $likes = $row['total_likes'];

    echo $likes; //output number of likes per post and pass it to ajax data success
}
?>
```

Using the codes above, if I have three posts (with a mix of 1, 2, and 0 likes), the alert under Ajax success as I noted "testing because I don't know how" will show a message: **1, 2, 0**, which is correct! The numbers are together in a single alert, fyi.

Now my question is how can I pass those values back to each post under likes div? What I mean is 1 like is for postid1, 2 likes for postid2, and 0 likes for postid3. Usually I select a single element and pass using .html, but how to do it if the php data returned is altogether (i.e. 2, 1, 0). I know I need to make adjustments here:

```js
success: function(data) {
    alert(data); //testing because I don't know how
}
```

Say I have this HTML:

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="postid">1</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah</div>
    <div class="likes">1</div> //pass the value back here
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="postid">2</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah</div>
    <div class="likes">2</div> //pass the value back here
</div>

<div class="post_3">
    <div class="postid">3</div>
    <div class="message">blah blah</div>
    <div class="likes">0</div> //pass the value back here
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you have typos in your HTML `</likes>` should be `</div>` and you're missing a closing `"` at the end of your `$likeQuery` in PHP.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Anyway what you should be doing in the PHP is building an array containing all the likes and then encoding that array as JSON before you output it. That way the JS will received the data in a usable structure, and then you can loop through it to get each value and place it into the HTML. (N.B. your JSON might want to be an array of objects, so each entry can contain the post ID, and the number of likes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have some sort of table to match what post has what likes. Then you can update the content of the `.likes` div of corresponsing post.

**Quick and dirty**

Since your PHP is already returing the string `"1, 2, 0"` for posts `1`, `2` and `3`, the minial effort would be to simply split that string in Javascript and then updated the `.likes` div in order:

```js
success: function(data) {
  var likes = data.split(", "); // likes will hold ["1", "2", "0"]
  $('.likes').each(function(i, likeDiv) {
    $(likeDiv).text(likes[i]);
  });
}
```

**This will work in your particular case but is relying on the fact that your HTML is ordered in the exact same way that your posts are in the database. So not very resilient.**

Instead I'd suggest you change your PHP to have both likes count *and* post id and echo the whole as JSON

**JSON**

PHP

```php
<?php
require_once '../connection.php';

$postID = trim(json_encode($_POST['postid']), '[]'); //convert array to string and remove square brackets to be a valid value for MySQL query

$likeQuery  = "select count(*) as total_likes from likes where post_id in ('.$postID.') group by post_id order by post_id desc"; //query number of likes
$likeResult = mysqli_query($conn, $likeQuery);

// build output collection
$output = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($likeResult)) { //loop through the query
    $output[] = [
        'post_id' => $row['post_id'],
        'likes'   => $row['total_likes']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($output);
// [{"post_id": 1, "likes": 1}, {"post_id": 2, "likes": 2}, {"post_id": 3, "likes": 0}]'
?>
```

JS

```js
success: function(data) {
  var postsLikes = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < postsLikes.length; i++) {

    // find corresponding post
    var $post = $('.postid').filter(function(j, postIdDiv) {
      return postIdDiv.textContent == postsLikes[i].post_id
    }).parent()

    // update likes count in post
    $post.find('.likes').text(postsLikes[i].likes)
  }
}
```